# How to cover service.map in Angular Test?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine

I'm new to Angular UT.

I find it difficult to cover this.service.map on my current test. This is the method I want to test:

```
validateSupervisorLevel(eid = '', supervisorLevel: number): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (
      control: AbstractControl
    ):
      | Promise<ValidationErrors | null>
      | Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
      if (isEmptyInputValue(control.value)) {
        return of(null);
      } else if (control.value === eid) {
        return this.mrdrService.getUserDetails(control.value).pipe(
          debounceTime(800),
          // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
          map((adUserDetails: MrdrDetails) => {
            const careerLevel = adUserDetails?.displayableCareerLevel;
            if (
              Number(careerLevel) <= supervisorLevel ||
              careerLevel === 'Accenture Leadership'
            ) {
              return null;
            }

            if (adUserDetails) {
              return { invalid_supervisor_level: true };
            } else {
              return { invalid_supervisor: true };
            }
          }),
          first()
        );
      } else {
        return control.valueChanges.pipe(
          debounceTime(800),
          take(1),
          concatMap((_) =>
            this.mrdrService.getUserDetails(control.value).pipe(
              debounceTime(800),
              // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
              map((adUserDetails: MrdrDetails) => {
                const careerLevel = adUserDetails?.displayableCareerLevel;
                if (
                  Number(careerLevel) <= supervisorLevel ||
                  careerLevel === 'Accenture Leadership'
                ) {
                  return null;
                }
                if (adUserDetails) {
                  return { invalid_supervisor_level: true };
                } else {
                  return { invalid_supervisor: true };
                }
              }),
              first(),
              catchError(() => {
                return of({ contactservicedown: true });
              })
            )
          )
        );
      }
    };
  }
```

and this is what i have done so far:

```
//start of validateSupervisorLevel
  it('should return null if control value is empty in validatesuperiorlevel',()=>{
    let mrdrService = TestBed.inject(IpdomainMrdrService);
    const mockMrdrDetails : MrdrDetails = {
      enterpriseId: 'earvin.nill.castillo',
      supervisorName: 'Earvin Castillo',
      displayableCareerLevel: '9'

    }
    let eid ='earvin.nill.castillo';
    let supervisorLevel=9;
    const controlValue : any = new FormControl();
    controlValue.setValue(null)

    const valid = validator.validateSupervisorLevel(eid,supervisorLevel)
    
    const result = valid(controlValue)
    expect(result).toBeDefined();
  
  })

   it('should return else if control value is empty in validatesuperiorlevel',()=>{
    let mrdrService = TestBed.inject(IpdomainMrdrService);
    const mockMrdrDetails : MrdrDetails = {
      enterpriseId: 'earvin.nill.castillo',
      supervisorName: 'Earvin Castillo',
      displayableCareerLevel: '9'

    }
    let eid ='earvin.nill.castillo';
    let supervisorLevel=9;
    const controlValue : any = new FormControl();
    controlValue.setValue('earvin.nill.castillo')

    const valid = validator.validateSupervisorLevel(eid,supervisorLevel)
    
    const result = valid(controlValue)
    getuserdet.MrdrDetails = mockMrdrDetails
    getuserdet.MrdrDetails.displayableCareerLevel = mockMrdrDetails.displayableCareerLevel
    expect(result).toBeDefined();
  
  })
```

The problem is I've tried other work around to cover the this.service and .map and I can't seem to cover it well

Coverage:

[Coverage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0O3V.png)

I tried mocking the service but ended up still not covering it.